# Responsive landing page for Paypal button?

Tags: paypal

Using a standard Paypal merchant account to create a pay button, integrated into a "button" on our CMS (mobeefox.com) via URL.

Using this standard function, end user lands on a non-responsive form.

Is it possible to create a URL towards a responsive landing page for payment without developping?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The user will only be redirected to responsive landing page if they use mobile device to access it. On desktop, the landing page will stay as it is. Also, note that the responsive page (or mobile-optimized page) will not work under certain circumstances such as if the button has discount amount etc. More information on it: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/mobile-paypal-payments-standard/#usecases